# mount.nfs: Connection timed out

Tags: server, mount, nfs

I am trying to mount a Synology NAS drive to my Ubuntu Server via NFS via this [tutorial](https://kb.synology.com/de-de/DSM/tutorial/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS) from Synology.

I completed these steps but after  `sudo mount` I only get `mount.nfs: Connection timed out`back. I assumed it was a problem with either `ufw`or the Synology firewall so I disabled them both for troubleshooting but it still didn't work. Now I assume I got my settings in the DSM wrong but after checking them a few times I can't see anything wrong.

The problem is I don't even know where to start troubleshooting. Is there a way to narrow down the reason for this problem?

To get a complete picture here are my settings in the Synology DMS where the blacked out IP is the IP of my Ubuntu Server:

[Settings 1 Synology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBUEz.png)

[Settings 2 Synology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rFy5.png)

And here are the used commands and the result:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nfs-common
sudo mount -t nfs ip_from_NAS:/volume1/media /nfs/temp-share

mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

So yeah if someone could help me out here that would be amazing, I don't even know where to start troubleshooting. If there's more info to post I'll gladly provide it but I also don't know what is needed, so anyway thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: "*Connection timed out*" means that no system reacted on the connection request to the specified IP address. This might mean that the NAS (or whatever device uses the IP address) ignored the request. Are you sure that the configuration of the NAS is correct? Do you have to  Did you use the correct IP address? Do the NAS and your Ubuntu Server use the same NFS version 3 or 4?

Comment: Did you check with a network sniffer like Wireshark what's happening on the network?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Even after checking everything multiple times I still got the wrong ip adress for my nas in the mount command. I got the right ip now and it works.

Answer (score 2):

After spending multiple hours and checking everything a few times I still got the wrong IP adress for my NAS in the mount command. I got the right IP now and it works. Don't be like me.

Comment: I was like you.  oops. also spend a hour. but this post made me triple check the ip.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to double check that you are on the same subnet.  Additionally, your router may have client isolation enabled.